# does new Hub site mega menu show the subsites under its associated site collection? how does this look? how does this affect navigation?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, sub-site, hub-site, megamenu

The mega menu is not yet available for my tenant and am wondering how it will show subsites - how that will look. I have a dilemma right now as to whether create an entirely new site that I will associate with the hub site, or create a subsite under an existing site associated with this hub site. I am considering a subsite because I want to use lookup columns to reference lists within the site collection. If I create an entirely new site I won't be able to do that. However, there has been some debate as to whether to create separate sites and associate with a hub or create a subsite. In this case I think I need a subsite, but I just don't know how that will play out navigation wise. I'd ideally like it to be an entirely different site because I think the topic of the site warrants it, but I'd lose that list association. We are only using one hub site at this time and in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

By default the mega menu does not show the subsites.
But you can add any links you want to show your subsites under their root sites.
The mega menu is displayed on the root site its subsites (as long as the root site is associated to the Hub)